# returning a joined array after manipulating values

Tags: javascript, arrays, join

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  var words = str.split(" ");
  var capsOn = "";
  var titleArray = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    
    capsOn = words[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + words[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();
    
    
   
  }
  
  return titleArray.join(" ");
  
}


titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

I am just stuck in this one line of code that will relate **capsOn** (which has the function of turning each element of the array words first letter into capital) with **titleArray** (which should return all the values of capsOn joined to form the whole sentence again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push the capitalized word into the array `titleArray`

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  var words = str.split(" ");
  var titleArray = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  //           +--- Right here!
  //           |    
  //           v
    titleArray.push(words[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + words[i].substring(1).toLowerCase());
  }
  
  return titleArray.join(" ");
  
}


console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

An alternative approach using regex and ES6 features (Spread syntax and Destructuring assignment):

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  var words = str.split(/\s+/g);
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var [letter, ...rest] = words[i].split('');    
    words[i] = letter.toUpperCase() + rest.join('').toLowerCase();
  }
  
  return words.join(" ");  
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a                little tea pot"));
```

An alternative using the function `replace` and maintaining the original structure:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/\S*(.*?)\S+/g, function(word) {
    var [letter, ...rest] = word.trim().split('');   
    var spaces = word.match(/\s+/g).join('');
    return spaces + letter.toUpperCase() + rest.join('').toLowerCase()
  });
}

console.log(titleCase("       I'm a                little tea        pot       "));
```

Comment: or simply change to `words[i] = words[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + words[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();`, then `return words.join(" ")`; anyway, you are very close, only thing you need is join with `capitcal` words instead of old words or null.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the `map` function, after you `split` the `string`, it becomes `Array`, then you can use `map` to change each value of the `Array` into a new value

```
const titleCase = (str) => str.split(" ").map(
    element => element.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + element.substring(1)
  ).join(" ");

const result = titleCase(teapot);
console.log(result) //I'm A Little Tea Pot
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you better known the [lodash](https://lodash.com) libary that contain most of the basic functions on objects \ strings \ array \ etc

in your case, [Capitalize](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#capitalize) is lodash function that return a Capitalized version of the word

> FRED -> Fred
>
> fred -> Fred

second, you better use .map function, it's more clearly.
try that:

```
function titleCase(str) {
  return str.split(' ')
                .map(x => _.capitalize(x))
                .join(' ');

}
```

Good luck!